# Дихальний — це той, що для дихання. А як сказати "дихаючий" без -юч?

Tags: словотворення, дієприкметники

Ок, нехай активні дієприкметники теперішнього часу недоконаного виду не є літературною нормою. Нічого не маю проти заміни їх іменниками, прикметниками, пасивними дієприкметниками, описовими конструкціями. Вважаю, що форма "той, що" у багатьох випадках доречніша.
Допоможіть утворити суфіксальну конструкцію з "(матеріал), що дихає".

Comment: повітрянопроникний

Answer (score 4):

Гадаю, що у цьому словосполученні російське слово *дышащий*, переклад якому ви шукаєте прийшло до росіян як відповідник англомовному *breathable*. Давайте розберемось зі значенням цього слова в англійській мові:

1. Атмосферу, якою можна дихати.
2. Тканину крізь яку може проходити повітря.

[-able](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/able_2) використовують разом з дієсловом, щоб утворити прикметник, який описує щось, що можна зробити. Наприклад, enjoyable (цим можна насолоджуватись), breakable (це легко зламати).

Я не знаюсь на російській мові, але можливо у них прийнято наділяти речі людськими якостями, як-от казати, що тканина може дихати. Та, наскільки я знаю, українській мові це не притаманно. Наприклад, у книжці над якою ми зараз працюємо наш редактор скаржиться, що коли ми кажемо, що алгоритм ухвалює рішення, бо алгоритм це лише знаряддя людини (хоча із сьогоднішнім рівнем розвитку штучного інтелекту різниця вже не так помітна).

Пропоную не слідувати росіянам, а шукати відповідник прямо з англійської дотримуючись традицій нашої мови. Можу запропонувати **повітро/паро/газо+проникний/відводильний** матеріал.

Comment: Навіть із сьогоднішнім рівнем розвитку ШІ, це такі ж алгоритми. Це така ж обробки даних, робота з цифрами та числами. Ваш редактор - розумна людина.

Comment: > [дышащий] прийшло до росіян як відповідник англомовному breathable
А є щось, щоб підкріпити, крім "гадаю"? Бо я, наприклад, так не вважаю. А якщо не приймати ваше припущення, то подальший аналіз просто втрачає сенс.

Comment: @Physmatik відредагував

Answer (score 3):

Чесно кажучи, претензію сучасного "літературного стандарту" до активних дієприкметників не розумію (особливо на фоні адекватного сприйняття активних дієприслівників). Той же "дихаючий" використовували і Коцюбинський, і Винниченко, і Самчук, і ще [ряд інших](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac13&tab=advanced&keyword=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9&attrs=word%2Ctag&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&linenumbers=0&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&glue=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=doc%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.translator&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&checkboxes=0&fullcontext=1&f_tab=advanced&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A7767%7D%5D):

> Темна,тяжко дихаюча постать швидко виходить із кущів, прожогом кидається в алею й зникає в ній, часто, хапливо риплячи піском у тьмі. *Володимир Винниченко ● 1924 ● Сонячна машина*

> До домовини підступають перелякані, ледь дихаючі жінки, а чернець грубо попихає їх своїми сильними руками і басом підганяє: — Ну там! *Улас Самчук ● 1937 ● Волинь*

> Врешті вони розскочились із чудово-блискучими очима, зі схвильованими грудьми, з дихаючими вогнем ніздрями на блідих гордих обличчях… *Михайло Коцюбинський ● 1901 ● Дорогою ціною*

> Льошка обняв Марусю за плечі, і вони отак ішли — двоє як одне — живим, дихаючим степом. *Люко Дашвар ● 2008 ● Молоко з кров'ю*

> Вібромасажні крісла, дихаючі підгузки«Libero», чіпси«Екстрелла», продукція фірми«Дриґало» і«Шкварки від Одарки, європейська якість». *Ліна Костенко ● 2010 ● Записки українського самашедшого*

Активні дієприкметники до зворотних дієслів дійсно не звучать (вмивающийся? повертающийся?), але в решті...

Якщо ж воно таки муляє вам очі (або прикопався редактор), то можете використати щось типу "проникний [для повітря] матеріал", або, без суфіксально утворених слів, просто "матеріал дихає".

Comment: Краще не ставити лише посилання на інший ресурс, бо посилання може перестати працювати (наприклад через зміну формату url-адреси) і відповідь втратить цінність. Переносьте сюди хоча б головні приклади або ключову інформацію яка міститься на сторінці, на яку ви посилаєтесь. Дякую!

Answer (score 1):

Може **дихатий**? З [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&highlight=on):

Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)

> Огнём ды́шащий – огнедиха́тий. [Драко́н огнедиха́тий (Кул.)].

Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)

> Огнедиха́тий, -а, -е. Огнемъ дышащій. Дракон огнедихатий. К. МХ. 35.

Comment: Я ж не прошу створити нове слово. Я прошу конструкцію в межах дійсного, сучасного мовного корпусу.